# WFS filter without specifying exact geometry structure

Tags: arcgis-server, wfs, filter, ogc, getfeature

I'm trying to query a WFS-server for polygons with an Intersects-filter. The problem is that the server does not recognize "MultiSurface" or "surfaceMember" objects in a query, even though it serves the objects just fine. So I wonder if there is a way to create a filter query without specifying those two unknown objects?

Here is what a regular object gotten via GetFeature looks like on the server:

```
   <wfs:member>
    <Rajapinnat_GTK_Maapera_WFS:maapera_200k_maalajit gml:id="maapera_200k_maalajit.7">
        <Rajapinnat_GTK_Maapera_WFS:OBJECTID>7</Rajapinnat_GTK_Maapera_WFS:OBJECTID>
        <Rajapinnat_GTK_Maapera_WFS:PINTAMAALAJI_KOODI>19551822</Rajapinnat_GTK_Maapera_WFS:PINTAMAALAJI_KOODI>
        <Rajapinnat_GTK_Maapera_WFS:PINTAMAALAJI>Soistuma (Tvs) RT</Rajapinnat_GTK_Maapera_WFS:PINTAMAALAJI>
        <Rajapinnat_GTK_Maapera_WFS:POHJAMAALAJI_KOODI>195210</Rajapinnat_GTK_Maapera_WFS:POHJAMAALAJI_KOODI>
        <Rajapinnat_GTK_Maapera_WFS:POHJAMAALAJI>Sekalajitteinen maalaji, päälajitetta ei selvitetty (SY) RT</Rajapinnat_GTK_Maapera_WFS:POHJAMAALAJI>
        <Rajapinnat_GTK_Maapera_WFS:SHAPE>
            <gml:MultiSurface gml:id="maapera_200k_maalajit.7.pl" srsName="urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::4326" srsDimension="3">
                <gml:surfaceMember>
                    <gml:Polygon gml:id="maapera_200k_maalajit.7.pl.0" srsName="urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::4326" srsDimension="3">
                        <gml:exterior>
                            <gml:LinearRing>
                                <gml:posList>64.7776567308392 28.77604496803433 0 64.77731185704607 28.77681027379294 0 64.77697418184302 28.77810169414249 0 64.77684559667277 28.78088328084997 0 64.77663213390103 28.78299909789731 0 64.77662962840745 28.78385858858024 0 64.77524023392766 28.78552359668834 0 64.77486686166802 28.7857792553361 0 64.77456934266 28.78575698329444 0 64.77425769357333 28.78531478772545 0 64.77357802301179 28.78355407016347 0 64.77228597648866 28.78135226301311 0 64.77204589872534 28.78041550838147 0 64.77189087281546 28.77915901110361 0 64.77176168417115 28.77444029478147 0 64.77163066461482 28.77319119445554 0 64.7703848772379 28.76714685203607 0 64.76994728716335 28.76551397491946 0 64.76962564830792 28.76471243234543 0 64.76933156817577 28.76437488808297 0 64.76857590271457 28.76396612704263 0 64.76825863553955 28.76356207593914 0 64.76749800215595 28.76193090033586 0 64.76701948116823 28.76042230868303 0 64.76677059138972 28.76008217699485 0 64.76640434200374 28.76005102231276 0 64.76578039151188 28.76034064045517 0 64.76474893138877 28.76135706712327 0 64.76401152509376 28.7612816485182 0 64.76420778775493 28.76009226642811 0 64.76424423836797 28.75872494281848 0 64.76402258299203 28.75814566713127 0 64.76326716552853 28.75777732744886 0 64.76269450319469 28.75701898614951 0 64.76230619139065 28.75681645667067 0 64.7624946126009 28.75474957524565 0 64.76232652956053 28.75086338597574 0 64.76288765928767 28.75165967680441 0 64.76344829871745 28.75180616740619 0 64.76407102172698 28.75143220048357 0 64.76498016376971 28.75062418151745 0 64.76617117302182 28.75023952345639 0 64.7671179999509 28.74923642555283 0 64.76683984521924 28.7504027786423 0 64.76673175224172 28.75181499863326 0 64.76679388073789 28.75300846986585 0 64.76695672524447 28.7541098930138 0 64.76719530950163 28.75508010023858 0 64.7676397765015 28.75626714034336 0 64.76777954326909 28.75695773603269 0 64.76789531287329 28.75814577947415 0 64.76794354931928 28.75989389332741 0 64.76811971724834 28.76110988484289 0 64.76850611577967 28.76222470659916 0 64.76895005750166 28.76277143271336 0 64.76948882085961 28.76283070213009 0 64.76984186294776 28.76219992193966 0 64.76997246427915 28.76135423353771 0 64.76985202049536 28.75967996611625 0 64.76983459317681 28.75774519894948 0 64.77027206168513 28.75565227788326 0 64.77039087910775 28.75414809930211 0 64.77035922138444 28.75384427495596 0 64.77142016642408 28.75479227210799 0 64.77253260281284 28.75501076992303 0 64.77213860273307 28.75571039673528 0 64.77151618557674 28.75648769153383 0 64.7713841344743 28.75719506401458 0 64.77143342696729 28.75799562621807 0 64.77158278477056 28.75878636869002 0 64.77208449893168 28.75977677886423 0 64.77253281402488 28.75998784661731 0 64.77356611922914 28.75905904152197 0 64.77437606193499 28.75876808041859 0 64.77521659426161 28.75931209965968 0 64.77585980456895 28.76036968541313 0 64.7761603763291 28.76028786119013 0 64.77650204912646 28.75959261617334 0 64.77645533224715 28.7579816758234 0 64.77665976160861 28.75701174503364 0 64.77773520245289 28.75375305882119 0 64.77824968555235 28.75282469426798 0 64.77816494215897 28.75475820265029 0 64.77828896600329 28.75665300152396 0 64.77856597518674 28.75807178189937 0 64.77949176937001 28.76171007415529 0 64.77947923899205 28.76320096115341 0 64.77924489458422 28.76424301523251 0 64.77878289564178 28.76499188502278 0 64.77836692714426 28.76515365553666 0 64.77814877533535 28.76482968089153 0 64.77762231981832 28.76350986678476 0 64.77676581333682 28.76226047890544 0 64.77508908645356 28.76104335905945 0 64.77410735806583 28.76090467985607 0 64.77355197786588 28.76145626806542 0 64.77301539088511 28.76286935783035 0 64.77267359522054 28.76451451660772 0 64.77252072377814 28.76657677619422 0 64.77256029327985 28.76770958412544 0 64.77273691069158 28.76910147041103 0 64.77349212192205 28.77338557571758 0 64.77379283058299 28.77434094837355 0 64.77449933062123 28.77499763235045 0 64.77547087503322 28.77510154270241 0 64.77612760889062 28.77585329316086 0 64.77650125266277 28.77608116554261 0 64.77711687995877 28.77619232032888 0 64.7776567308392 28.77604496803433 0</gml:posList>
                            </gml:LinearRing>
                        </gml:exterior>
                    </gml:Polygon>
                </gml:surfaceMember>
            </gml:MultiSurface>
        </Rajapinnat_GTK_Maapera_WFS:SHAPE>
        <Rajapinnat_GTK_Maapera_WFS:SHAPE.AREA>878167.4457516751</Rajapinnat_GTK_Maapera_WFS:SHAPE.AREA>
        <Rajapinnat_GTK_Maapera_WFS:SHAPE.LEN>8968.530418892669</Rajapinnat_GTK_Maapera_WFS:SHAPE.LEN>
    </Rajapinnat_GTK_Maapera_WFS:maapera_200k_maalajit>
</wfs:member>
```

Here is what what my filtering query looks like:

```
    <wfs:GetFeature
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs/2.0" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2" xmlns:GTKWFS="http://server.server"
service="WFS"
version="2.0.0"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wfs
http://schemas.opengis.net/wfs/2.0.0/wfs.xsd"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <wfs:Query typeName="GTKWFS:maapera_50k" srsName="EPSG:4326" xmlns:LiVi="http://172.17.14.211:8080/LiVi">
    <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
      <ogc:Intersects>
        <ogc:ValueReference>GTKWFS:SHAPE</ogc:ValueReference>
            <gml:MultiSurface>
                <gml:surfaceMember>
                    <gml:Polygon srsName="urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::4326">
                        <gml:exterior>
                            <gml:LinearRing>
                                <gml:posList>64.7776567308392 28.77604496803433 0 64.77731185704607 28.77681027379294 0 64.77697418184302 28.77810169414249 0 64.77684559667277 28.78088328084997 0 64.77663213390103 28.78299909789731 0 64.77662962840745 28.78385858858024 0 64.77524023392766 28.78552359668834 0 64.77486686166802 28.7857792553361 0 64.77456934266 28.78575698329444 0 64.77425769357333 28.78531478772545 0 64.77357802301179 28.78355407016347 0 64.77228597648866 28.78135226301311 0 64.77204589872534 28.78041550838147 0 64.77189087281546 28.77915901110361 0 64.77176168417115 28.77444029478147 0 64.77163066461482 28.77319119445554 0 64.7703848772379 28.76714685203607 0 64.76994728716335 28.76551397491946 0 64.76962564830792 28.76471243234543 0 64.76933156817577 28.76437488808297 0 64.76857590271457 28.76396612704263 0 64.76825863553955 28.76356207593914 0 64.76749800215595 28.76193090033586 0 64.76701948116823 28.76042230868303 0 64.76677059138972 28.76008217699485 0 64.76640434200374 28.76005102231276 0 64.76578039151188 28.76034064045517 0 64.76474893138877 28.76135706712327 0 64.76401152509376 28.7612816485182 0 64.76420778775493 28.76009226642811 0 64.76424423836797 28.75872494281848 0 64.76402258299203 28.75814566713127 0 64.76326716552853 28.75777732744886 0 64.76269450319469 28.75701898614951 0 64.76230619139065 28.75681645667067 0 64.7624946126009 28.75474957524565 0 64.76232652956053 28.75086338597574 0 64.76288765928767 28.75165967680441 0 64.76344829871745 28.75180616740619 0 64.76407102172698 28.75143220048357 0 64.76498016376971 28.75062418151745 0 64.76617117302182 28.75023952345639 0 64.7671179999509 28.74923642555283 0 64.76683984521924 28.7504027786423 0 64.76673175224172 28.75181499863326 0 64.76679388073789 28.75300846986585 0 64.76695672524447 28.7541098930138 0 64.76719530950163 28.75508010023858 0 64.7676397765015 28.75626714034336 0 64.76777954326909 28.75695773603269 0 64.76789531287329 28.75814577947415 0 64.76794354931928 28.75989389332741 0 64.76811971724834 28.76110988484289 0 64.76850611577967 28.76222470659916 0 64.76895005750166 28.76277143271336 0 64.76948882085961 28.76283070213009 0 64.76984186294776 28.76219992193966 0 64.76997246427915 28.76135423353771 0 64.76985202049536 28.75967996611625 0 64.76983459317681 28.75774519894948 0 64.77027206168513 28.75565227788326 0 64.77039087910775 28.75414809930211 0 64.77035922138444 28.75384427495596 0 64.77142016642408 28.75479227210799 0 64.77253260281284 28.75501076992303 0 64.77213860273307 28.75571039673528 0 64.77151618557674 28.75648769153383 0 64.7713841344743 28.75719506401458 0 64.77143342696729 28.75799562621807 0 64.77158278477056 28.75878636869002 0 64.77208449893168 28.75977677886423 0 64.77253281402488 28.75998784661731 0 64.77356611922914 28.75905904152197 0 64.77437606193499 28.75876808041859 0 64.77521659426161 28.75931209965968 0 64.77585980456895 28.76036968541313 0 64.7761603763291 28.76028786119013 0 64.77650204912646 28.75959261617334 0 64.77645533224715 28.7579816758234 0 64.77665976160861 28.75701174503364 0 64.77773520245289 28.75375305882119 0 64.77824968555235 28.75282469426798 0 64.77816494215897 28.75475820265029 0 64.77828896600329 28.75665300152396 0 64.77856597518674 28.75807178189937 0 64.77949176937001 28.76171007415529 0 64.77947923899205 28.76320096115341 0 64.77924489458422 28.76424301523251 0 64.77878289564178 28.76499188502278 0 64.77836692714426 28.76515365553666 0 64.77814877533535 28.76482968089153 0 64.77762231981832 28.76350986678476 0 64.77676581333682 28.76226047890544 0 64.77508908645356 28.76104335905945 0 64.77410735806583 28.76090467985607 0 64.77355197786588 28.76145626806542 0 64.77301539088511 28.76286935783035 0 64.77267359522054 28.76451451660772 0 64.77252072377814 28.76657677619422 0 64.77256029327985 28.76770958412544 0 64.77273691069158 28.76910147041103 0 64.77349212192205 28.77338557571758 0 64.77379283058299 28.77434094837355 0 64.77449933062123 28.77499763235045 0 64.77547087503322 28.77510154270241 0 64.77612760889062 28.77585329316086 0 64.77650125266277 28.77608116554261 0 64.77711687995877 28.77619232032888 0 64.7776567308392 28.77604496803433 0
                            </gml:posList>
                        </gml:LinearRing>
                    </gml:exterior>
                </gml:Polygon>
            </gml:surfaceMember>
         </gml:MultiSurface>
      </ogc:Intersects>
    </ogc:Filter>
  </wfs:Query>
</wfs:GetFeature>
```

And here is the response with "Unknown geometry type was found error", caused by "MultiSurface" and "surfaceMember":

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ExceptionReport
 version="2.0.0" xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/ows/1.1"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/ows/1.1 http://schemas.opengis.net/ows/1.1.0/owsAll.xsd"
>
    <Exception exceptionCode="InvalidParameterValue" locator="Unknown">
        <ExceptionText>
            <![CDATA[Unknown geometry type was found.]]>
        </ExceptionText>
    </Exception>
    <Exception exceptionCode="OperationProcessingFailed" locator="Unknown">
        <ExceptionText>
            <![CDATA[Operator 'Intersects' can't parse geometry.]]>
        </ExceptionText>
    </Exception>
</ExceptionReport>
```

Is there a way to query without specifying "MultiSurface" or "surfaceMember"? I don't have access to the ArcGIS server. The available OGC versions are 1.0.0, 1.1.0, and 2.0.0.

Comment: `<wfs:Query typeName="GTKWFS:maapera_50k" ` parameter must be `typeNames` for WFS 2.0.0

Comment: That's true, but does not seem to fix the problem. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Have you tried with plain polygon?